# Traduzindo Identity pt-br

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Estou utilizando o `Identity` em minha aplicação `MVC 5.2.3`

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1
```

instalei também o pacote de tradução do mesmo

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.pt-br 2.2.1
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.pt-br 5.2.3
Microsoft.Owin.pt-br 3.1.0
```

Porém algumas mensagens de erro ainda estão em inglês.

> Passwords must have at least one digit ('0'-'9').

Verifiquei e o arquivo `EditUserViewModel.cs` está com todos os textos de validação em pt-br

No web.config tbm setei

```
<globalization uiCulture="pt" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="false" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

O que falta pra essa mensagem ficar em pt-br?

Comment: Veja se [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40801250/7762411) do SOen pode ajudar

Comment: Jovem, onde que você pôs a tag `globalization` no seu web.config?

Comment: @LINQ é a primeira tag após abrir <system.web>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, você precisa ir no Global.asax e adicionar o método abaixo.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Acredito que já foi feito isso, pela indicação do web.config na pergunta. Esta instrução somente duplicaria ou sobreescreveria o que foi feito no web.config.

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema quando utilizei a configuração do web.config, porém ao ler um pouco mais a documentação encontrei essa solução e funcionou perfeitamente para minha aplicação

Comment: realmente achei meio redudante, pq aqui seta em código o que defini no web.config, porém pelos testes iniciais, funcionou! coisa do capeta!

Comment: Não sei se é uma boa prática, o código funcionou, converteu a tradução, mas desde então percebe-se levemente uma queda de performance na aplicação.

Answer (score -2):

Faça uma busca pela frase, pois se não estou enganado a mesma fica na parte de configurações da senha. Não me recordo exatamente onde, mas fica na parte de configurações de regras para criação da senha, onde por exemplo, vc diz para o Identity que a senha precisa ter letras, números e símbolos.

Acho que fica no ApplicationUserManager.